# Display sum of bound numeric values in XML

Tags: sapui5

I am using an OData model to bind UI controls with values. I need to sum two values from model values.

```xml
 <Input id="__input8" class="rt1" value="{D1}" maxLength="1" type="Number" placeholder="" enabled="true" editable="true" />
 <Input id="__input9" class="rt1" value="{D2}" maxLength="1" type="Number" placeholder="" enabled="true" editable="true" />
 <Text id="__input15" class="rt1" text="{D1} + {D2}" />
```

I need to sum the `D1` and `D2` values in the Text control. I am using XML for view and JS for controller.

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, true);
var oJsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.read("/xxxSet?", null, null, true, function (oData,repsonse) {
        oJsonModel.setData(oData);
});   
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

This is my OData connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [Expression Binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html):

```xml
 <Text id="__input15" class="rt1" text="{= ${D1} + ${D2}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks aborjinik, but its not working. i have tried {=${D1}+${D2}}  this works fine.. thanks friend..

Answer (score -1):

Nice, finally a post where i can help.

First, i would set a formatter. Since my root usually is sap.ui.app, and my formatter is inside a model folder and called formatter, i can call it like "sap.ui.app.model.formatter"

You can check whats the name of your root inside your index.

```
  data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"sap.ui.app": "./"}'>
```

Thats your root. Create a folder inside sap.ui.app named model, and inside the model create a file called formatter.js and inside the file write this code.

```
jQuery.sap.declare("sap.ui.app.model.formatter");
sap.ui.app.model.formatter = 
{
 function1: (a, b)
 {
 return a+b;
 }
};
```

Next, you should call the formatter from your view.

```
 <Text id="__input15" class="rt1" text="{parts:[{path : 'D1'}, {path : 'D2'}], formatter:'sap.ui.app.model.formatter.function1'}" />
```

Thats it. It should work now.

EDIT: I'm glad my answer helped.